# Eclipse doesn't use the path set in .bashrc

Tags: linux, eclipse, bash, ubuntu

whenever I run eclipse from the shortcut I am unable to correctly build some of my projects because the `PATH` variable that I configured in `.bashrc` doesn't get used.

When I run eclipse from my terminal, I can build all my projects perfectly fine because it's running through the correct shell.

The problem is that I want to use the `PATH` variable from my `.bashrc` without permanently having a terminal open. I tried this before, but every day I accidentally close the terminal that's running eclipse by accident and lose all my unsaved code.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two options for this problem:

- write a small script, export those vars or source your .bashrc before you start your eclipse.
- define those variables in /etc/environment. then they are not user-scope any more.

I prefer the 1st option.

Comment: I added the path variable to my .gnomerc file (which is basically the same as the second option)

Comment: Also similar to second option, I was able (on my Mint linux) to get this to work by adding my additional PATH manipulation to the ~/.profile file, which is run on login.

Comment: Option 3) starting Eclipse from inside bash. At least with Qt Creator it works without any issues.

Answer (score 21):

Your tooling probably utilizes the embedded eclipse terminal. This terminal does not start providing your login/user shell. So you need to set the eclipse terminal in your Eclipse preferences to start as `--login` shell:

Go to:

```
Preferences -> Terminal -> Local Terminal
```

and set

```
"Arguments" to "--login"
```

restart Eclipse and your users $PATH should be used from now on.

Comment: Legend! This is the best and simplest answer imo

Comment: I don't see this option in Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.3)

Comment: dont have to restart eclipse just reload terminal

Comment: Does not work with environment variables set in .zshrc on Mac.

Comment: To make it work on Mac, open a terminal and type `open -a Eclipse`. This makes Eclipse inherit the environment from the terminal.

Comment: Who uses terminal in eclipse? How about build targets? They will use unchanged PATH because Eclipse do not run them in terminal.

Answer (score 12):

1. Edit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop with write privileges, i.e. `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`
2. Change the setting `Exec=/usr/bin/eclipse` to `Exec=bash -ic "/usr/bin/eclipse"` and save

The underlying issue is that .bashrc is not loaded in a non-interactive shell. When you start Eclipse normally clicking on its symbol, `.bashrc` quits early. This solution applies to all programs that are defined by a `.desktop` file.
In contrast, `bash -i` opens an interactive shell, `-c ""` runs a command in that shell.

Comment: +1 Yes, this indeed the best and most non-intrusive way to do it. Plus it can be applied to many other applications. I start my Qt Creator in the exact same way.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create simple script

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> source /home/user/.environment_variables
> /home/user/eclipse_cpp/eclipse -Duser.name="My Name"
> ```

2.
Next put your all system variables in file /home/user/.environment_variables (any file you want)

My looks like:

```
export COCOS_ROOT=/home/user/Projects/edukoala
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```

3.
Now you can delete your variables in .bashrc and put line

```
source /home/user/.environment_variables
```

Everything works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is already answered and the answer has been accepted. But this will also work for running your code using Eclipse. You can edit the Run Configurations and set the environment variable there. Then, Eclipse will pick up the variable from this setting while building.