# Global environment variables in Eclipse and Yosemite

Tags: c, eclipse, macos, mpi, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to get a setup working for developing mpi programs using Eclipse on OSX Yosemite. My mpi installation was done via homebrew and I have added /usr/local/bin to my path via .bash_profile.

My problem is, that when I open Eclipse mpicc is not in my path. I could manually add it to the project configurations or add a PATH environment variable to the project and that would compile, but I can't use Eclipse PTP tools because it still can't find the mpi binaries.

So my question is, how do I configure Eclipse to include /usr/local/bin into it's path?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch mac eclipse with environment variables set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829749/launch-mac-eclipse-with-environment-variables-set)

Comment: Also: https://superuser.com/questions/28344/path-env-variable-on-mac-os-x-and-or-eclipse

Comment: The first link worked man, thanks! I was hoping for a "general" answer and that one seems to only work for Eclipse, but it solves my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by Alexander O'Mara was correct, so for anyone looking at this, please refer to [Launch mac eclipse with environment variables set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829749/launch-mac-eclipse-with-environment-variables-set)