# ProcessBuilder start() method to run command (ffprobe) in eclipse/mac

Tags: java, eclipse, processbuilder, ffprobe

I have installed ffprobe in mac and the directory is /usr/local/bin/ffprobe. When I run the ffprobe command in terminal, it works fine but when I run it in eclipse through ProcessBuilder, it does not run and throws exception as **`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ffprobe": error=2, No such file or directory.`**
But, when I run ProcessBuilder giving the absolute path of ffprobe, it works fine.

Working code:

```
sample args:[/usr/local/bin/ffprobe, -v, quiet, -print_format, json, -show_format, -show_streams, some_url]

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArgs);
Process proc = pb.start();
```

But, if args is `[ffprobe, -v, quiet, -print_format, json, -show_format, -show_streams, some_url]`

it throws error. How can I run ffprobe command without giving absolute path? I have already followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048216/environment-variables-in-eclipse?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but could not help on my issue.

My java process in eclipse is running at

```
Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Comment: Stupid question, but is `/usr/local/bin/` in the `PATH` for the Java process (not for your terminal, unless you're running from the command line)

Comment: Yes. I can run ffprobe command in eclipse terminal as well. When I print the path of ffprobe in java code, its clearly showing /usr/local/bin/ffprobe

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to resolve this with the below steps as mentioned by Sakra at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829749/launch-mac-eclipse-with-environment-variables-set?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) post:

1. Create eclipse.sh at /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/

> ```
> export ENV_VAR1=/usr/local/bin/
> logger "`dirname \"$0\"`/eclipse"
> exec "`dirname \"$0\"`/eclipse" $@
> ```

2. chmod +x /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.sh
3. Open the Eclipse.app Info.plist and change the value for the key CFBundleExecutable from eclipse to eclipse.sh.
4. Force update the LaunchService as

   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -v -f /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app