# Change password in SQL Developer after ORA-28001 the password has expired

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When trying to connect to my database with Oracle SQL Developer, I am getting the error:

> ORA-28001 the password has expired

How can I change my password in SQL Developer?

Comment: Why are you asking if you immediately answer the question yourself?

Comment: @hol - [answering your own question is encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), even if you know the answer before you post. I think this is off-topic though.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks. That was new to me. Yes it is off-topic.

Comment: Proper answer is to use sqlplus - if this is just expiration & account is not locked you will be offered to change password

Comment: why is this off-topic? The question & answer is very helpful

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Open SQL Developer and perform the following steps:

1. Right click on Connections > New Connection.

   - **Connection Name**: sys
   - **Username**: sys as sysdba
   - **Password**: sys (or your sys password)
   - **Hostname**: your database server IP
   - **Port**: **1521**
   - **SID**: your sid

   click connect.
2. Expand other users, and choose the user with the expired password. Right click and "edit" the user, enter the new password and confirm it.

   If you want your password to never expire again uncheck the box for password expiry.

Comment: What if you are not sysdba and just want a simple prompt to change your password ?

Comment: sqlplus / as sysdba   then 'alter user system identified by "YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD";'

Comment: This guy is gold ...

Comment: Some versions of SQL Developer allow resetting an expired non-locked password. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15278400/5286208