# ORA-28000: the account is locked error getting frequently

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I am facing this error given below :

```
 ORA-28000: the account is locked
```

Is this a DB Issue ? Whenever I unlock the user account using the alter SQL query, that is `ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK`, it will be temporarily OK.

Then after sometime the same account gets locked again. The database is using oracle `XE` version. Does anybody else have the same issue?

Comment: Most likely, some process is trying to log in to that account using an incorrect password on some sort of schedule.  I'd guess that the account is being locked because it's exceeding the number of allowed incorrect logins.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

One of the reasons of your problem could be the password policy you are using.

And if there is no such policy of yours then check your settings for the password properties in the `DEFAULT` profile with the following query:

```
SELECT resource_name, limit
FROM dba_profiles 
WHERE profile = 'DEFAULT'
AND resource_type = 'PASSWORD';
```

And If required, you just need to change the `PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME` to `unlimited` with the following query:

```
ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;
```

And this [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310) might be helpful for your problem.

Answer (score 49):

Way to unlock the user :

```
$ sqlplus  /nolog
SQL > conn sys as sysdba
SQL > ALTER USER USER_NAME ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

and open new terminal

```
SQL > sqlplus / as sysdba
connected
SQL > conn username/password  //which username u gave before unlock
```

- it will ask new `password:password`
- it will ask re-type `password:password`
- press enter you will get logged in

Comment: If the account was locked due to expired password, it may be needed to reset the password to make login usable again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086332/changing-password-with-oracles-sql-developer

Answer (score 17):

Here other solution to **only unlock the blocked user**. From your command prompt log as SYSDBA:

```
sqlplus "/ as sysdba"
```

Then type the following command:

```
alter user <your_username> account unlock;
```

Answer (score 7):

Check the `PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME` parameter. If it is set to 1 then you won't be able to unlock the password for 1 day even after you issue the `alter user unlock` command.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced this similar issue and resolved it by using following steps :

1. Open windows command prompt.
2. Login using the command `sqlplus "/ as sysdba"`
3. Then executed the command `alter user HR identified by password account unlock`


   Please note, the `password` is the password that I have used. 
   By using above steps you can connect to Oracle Database as user HR with the password password.

Answer (score 5):

### Solution 01

Account Unlock by using below query :

```
SQL> select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS from dba_users where username='ABCD_DEV';    
USERNAME             ACCOUNT_STATUS
-------------------- --------------------------------
ABCD_DEV       LOCKED

SQL> alter user ABCD_DEV account unlock;    
User altered.

SQL> select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS from dba_users where username='ABCD_DEV';    
USERNAME             ACCOUNT_STATUS
-------------------- --------------------------------
ABCD_DEV       OPEN
```

### Solution 02

Check `PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME` parameter by using below query :

```
SELECT resource_name, limit FROM dba_profiles WHERE profile = 'DEFAULT' AND resource_type = 'PASSWORD';

RESOURCE_NAME                    LIMIT
-------------------------------- ------------------------------
FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS            10
PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME               10
PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME              10
PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX               UNLIMITED
PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION         NULL
PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME               1
PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME              7
INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_TIME            UNLIMITED
```

Change the parameter using below query

```
ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;
```

Answer (score 4):

Login to SQL Plus client on the oracle database server machine.

enter user-name: **system**

enter password: **password** [Only if, if you have not changed your default password while DB installation]

press enter. after which, you will be seeing the connection status.

Now,

```
SQL> ALTER USER [USER_NAME] ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

press enter.

you will be seeing message: `user altered.`

Now try login with the user name on  db client[sqldeveloper].

Answer (score 2):

This issue produced due to exceeded the FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS, so we can get that from

> SELECT resource_name, limit FROM dba_profiles
> WHERE profile = 'DEFAULT' AND resource_type = 'PASSWORD';

Then we can get users states which means account is locked or open

> SELECT * FROM DBA_USERS;

If the particular user account locked, you can altered that to UNLOCK by

> ALTER USER {Account} ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

And if you want to increase the number of FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS, you can use

> ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS UNLIMITED;

Answer (score 1):

**Unlock the particular user account with username:**

> ALTER USER [USER_NAME] ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

**Unlock all the user accounts**

> SELECT 'alter user ' || username || ' account unlock;' FROM dba_users;

Answer (score 0):

In my case (i'm using container) it was because of APEX_PUBLIC_USER was locked.
Strange, because i'm starting container with -e IGNORE_APEX=TRUE.