# How to reset username and password for oracle

Tags: oracle

I am using

> Run SQL Command Line

to connect with database, previously I am able to connect with username 'system' and password 'root' but when I tried to connect using `SQL>connect system/root`

it is showing error

```
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

All services are running, after long time I am trying to connect may be I forgot my credentials can anyone help me how to change or reset both username and password I am on windows platform,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing password with oracle's SQL Developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086332/changing-password-with-oracles-sql-developer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too reset my password few days back.
You can reset your password by this

```
ALTER USER username IDENTIFIED BY password
```

Connect to db first

```
SQL> conn /as sysdba
```

More information [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4003.htm#i2058207)

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, when I tried to run the command you recommended, getting 'SP2-0640: Not connected'

Comment: You are not connected to the db. Run this command SQL> conn /as sysdba

Comment: may be I tried too many attempts my account i locked "ERROR:
ORA-28000: the account is locked", but with your command I altered details, Is it possible to unlock the locked account?

Comment: yes. you can unlock using : alter user username account unlock;