# Where can I locate the file "launchd.conf" in a Mac OSX

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I want to change permanently the number limit of open files.

I found that I should add this line in the file "/etc/launchd.conf", but I don't find this file.

Where can I find and edit it?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't exist by default (because the default configuration doesn't need to override anything), but you can create it.

Comment: [the answers found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770411/mac-os-x-lion-no-longer-recognizes-environment-plist) may help marc, too