# Mac OS X 10.8.1 - Files no longer being watched

Tags: macos, inotify

Just updated to OS X 10.8.1. I'm not sure if this is the cause, but basically immediately after, programs are unable to check for file changes.

In my makefile, the following command does not work (it doesn't trigger on file changes)

```
watchr -e "watch('scripts/.*\.js') {system 'make scripts'}"
```

On Sublime Text, when I make a new file in a folder, that new file is not shown in the sidebar, but it is created correctly in the directly.

This command, however works (based on Node's watch command, I believe):

```
stylus -w -u nib styles/ie8.styl -o public/styles
```

Anyone know what's going on or how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This isn't working now after rebooting again. I hate this! :/

I also ran into this issue with Sublime Text 2 as well as Guard (it started using a polling fallback).

I believe I found a fix:

1. Download [Onyx](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11582/onyx) and run it with all of the options under the automation tab checked
2. After it's done shut down your machine and turn it back on

At this point I was suddenly able to see new directories created using mkdir in terminal from within the Sublime Text 2 file browser. Guard was also working without the polling fallback.

I hope this helps, it was really starting to get on my nerves.

Comment: Sorry, it does not. When I was looking at it the other day it worked twice (at random) in about 10 reboots and would work only until the next time I restarted.

Comment: Things have gotten worse... My finder doesnt update file listings either now. Ugh

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be very informative but maybe it will help...

There is a thread in the Sublime Text forums [discussing this issue](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4667&start=20) and it doesn't seem to be secluded to OS X 10.8.1.

There also seems to be a thread about [watchr not always working](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr/issues/38), and that issue seems to be platform independent as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you've become the unwitting victim of the 'Mac OSX' env vars change ...

Please take a look at the following to determine if your env vars are set correctly on Mountain Lion as the environment.plist is now deprecated ...

[Env Plist Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770411/mac-os-x-lion-no-longer-recognizes-environment-plist)
[Mac OSX - Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8892)