# Replace Xcode's git with downloaded latest 1.8.3

Tags: xcode, macos, git

I want to use latest version of git (**1.8.3**).

Currently when I make `git --version` it shows me `git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)` which was installed together with Xcode I suppose.

I installed newest version but still bash uses Xcode one..

Please advice me how to override xcode git with the path that is installed to `usr/local/bin`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit ~/.bash_profile and add

```
alias git=/usr/local/bin/git
```

Source the bash_profile file or restart bash (source ~/.bash_profile)

See what git --version prints. 
I am not sure if this affects XCode. I never use versioning tools in IDEs, I do it from the command line

Or you add /usr/local/bin to $PATH to your bash_profile. I do this with macports or better said macports alters your bash_profile automatically.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: yeah, it works fine but I thought there could be another way with adding to $PATH, isn't it?

Comment: Yup see my updated answer, should also work instead of the alias.

Comment: Changing the $PATH in bash_profile won't work for Xcode as it isn't launched from a terminal session. You'll need to set the environment variables differently, eg see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770411/mac-os-x-lion-no-longer-recognizes-environment-plist

Comment: Kosmetika did "git --version" in a shell. My answer will work in this case. I told him it might not work in XCode.

Comment: For what it's worth, the file you need to edit if you're using ZSH instead of BASH is ~/.zshrc (YMMV based on your configuration).

Comment: yes but the ask was to replace xcode's git -- as I understood it -- anyway :) k

Answer (score 1):

Use a symbolic link to make Xcode use the /usr/local/bin/git instead of its built-in git

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/
sudo mv git xcodeGIt
sudo ln -s git /usr/local/git
```

Disclaimer: typed inline -- but thats how it works. Done it and it works fine for me

Comment: maybe (depending on what you need) you also want to ln -s the following: git-receive-pack   git-upload-archive
git-cvsserver      git-shell          git-upload-pack