# Mac Yosomite (10.10.4) : From Eclipse terminal mvn -version does't work

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven

I have configured external maven in eclipse however when I try to use `mvn -version` from eclipse terminal (shown in the image background) it says command not found. All `mvn` commands work from mac terminal though.

[image: external maven eclipse]
From terminal:
[image]
Content of my .bash_profile
[image]

I know `.bash_profile` is read when terminal is lunched and as eclipse is lunched from UI icon that is why these variables are not available there.

I read lot of articles which talks about setting up environment.plist and my.startup.plist. At the same time there are people saying these .plist files are no more supported in my mac version.
 
Article links:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks
[Mac OS X Lion no longer recognizes environment.plist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770411/mac-os-x-lion-no-longer-recognizes-environment-plist)

**Now I am totally confused how to make `mvn` work from eclipse terminal. Could somebody please show me a step to step guid.**

**Another follow up question:** on my mac terminal java - version works but when I print the list of environment variables no where I see JAVA_HOME, then how come `java - version` works. In above screen shoot you can see `mvn -- version` command was able to find java home.
[image]

Please help totally stuck at setting up the development environment.

Comment: Is there a chance you override the path when you launch Eclipse? You could use the maven default run command or the specific ones. The maven plugin can help you define your commands or let you use the default ones (right-clic on your project/ run)

Comment: @XavierBouclet Overriding PATH that I don"t know know. How can I check that. Yes I can use the m2e which is already installed but I want to use the external maven not the embedded one.

Comment: Give eclipse the full path to the mvn executable.

Comment: You can tell Eclipse to use the external Maven instead of the embedded one. In the settings check the external to be the default one