# Per-application environment variables on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, environment-variables

There are several different ways documented of setting environment variables either system wide or per user, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x).

Are there any options for setting environment variables on a per-application basis?

E.g. Is there a way to use something like `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` or `launchd.conf` but have some variables only inherited by specific apps?

The only way I can think of is to modify each applications Info.plist, but this involves changing an applications bundle which doesn't seem like a terribly good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically this is done by wrapping the desired app in a small shell script or automator action that sets the environment variable and then launches the app. For example, I have an automator "application" that has the following rule:

```
Run Shell Script:
  NSZombiesEnabled=YES open /Applications/MyApp.app
```

When I want to launch it this way, I just run the automator action.