# Getting ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS to work on Mac OS X

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, environment-variables

Lint Error Checking tool that comes with Android Developer Tools has an optional setting for missing translations:

> You can require all regions to provide a full translation by setting
>   the environment variable ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS.

I tried setting this environment variable in Mac OS X Snow Leopard following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567308/16622), but I still can't see missing translations among Lint Warnings. It only works if I run it through Terminal.

How can I verify if an environment variable is visible within Eclipse? Are there any Android developers who got this working on Mac OS X, or is this an ADT bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac OS X, add this line to **/etc/launchd.conf** and restart your system

`setenv ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS 1`

It will work after that!