# Access to user environment variable

Tags: dart, dart-io

In my .bashrc file:

```bash
export DART_SDK=/home/nicolas/dart/dart-sdk
```

In command line, it works when I "echo" it. But I cannot see this user variable from `dart` with, I just see system variable but not mine:

```dart
var env = Platform.environment;
env.forEach((k,v) => print("Key=$k Value=$v"));
```

I tried:

- on windows and it works
- on mac but doesn't work

Is my user variable is not well defined? Is my code is bad? It's a bug?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using the following code:

```bash
import 'dart:io'; // Server side / command line only package.

main() {
  Map<String, String> env = Platform.environment;
  env.forEach((k, v) => print("Key=$k Value=$v"));
}
```

I was able to override environment variables on both Windows and Mac. On Mac I had to add the line to .bash_profile (.bashrc is not loaded on my Mac).

John

Here is the [link to Platform class docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/Platform-class.html)

Comment: Thanks, so my code is good. After some tests, the behaviour is strange : when I run from Dart Editor, I cannot see my user variable(linux and Mac OS), but I run it with command line it works ...

Comment: Hi Nicolas, this is likely because Dart Editor is not running inside a bash shell but spawned from the Dock or Finder which has it's own set of environment variables. See this post for how to control environment variables for launched application- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x