# Dart Node.js settings.env equivalent

Tags: dart

What is the equivalent statement in Dart for the Node Express code:

```
app.settings.env
```

as in

```
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

I've looked at [ArgResults](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/args/ArgResults.html) but I'm not clear as to how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings):

> **env** - Environment mode, defaults to process.env.NODE_ENV or "development"

The problem boils down to accessing environment variables, which has been addressed here: [Access to user environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636738/access-to-user-environment-variable)

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
    String env;
    if (Platform.environment.containsKey("DART_ENV")) {
        env = Platform.environment["DART_ENV"];
    } else {
        env = "development";
    }
}
```

`ArgResults` just parses command-line arguments, which is likely not what you want. Use `ArgParser` instead.