# Dart web app environmental variables

Tags: web-applications, environment-variables, dart, system-properties, deployment-descriptor

It would be nice to allow my Dart web app to hit different servers depending on what environment it was deployed on:

- DEV: `http://dev.myapp.com/someService`
- QA: `http://testing.myapp.com/someService`
- LIVE: `http://myapp.com/someService`

In Java, typically you'd have a deployment descriptor (`myapp.properties`) that the app reads off the runtime classpath, allowing you to specify a `myapp.properties` on DEV like so:

```
service.url=dev.myapp.com/someService
```

And on QA like so:

```
service.url=qa.myapp/com/someService
```

etc. It looks like Dart offers something [*comparable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636738/access-to-user-environment-variable) **however its server-side/command-line only...**

So how do Dart web developers achieve the same thing, where you don't need to hardcode all of your various environments' servers into the app? (Obviously, this question extends *beyond* service URLs and really applies to any environment-specific property.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [String.fromEnvironment](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/String.html#fromEnvironment) constant constructors to get values passed to the dart2js compilers. For a full explaination on this new functionality check out Seth Ladd's blog post: [Compile-time dead code elimination with dart2js](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/12/compile-time-dead-code-elimination-with.html)

Comment: Thanks @Matt B (+1) - can I pass those arguments into dart2j *through* `pub build` somehow? In other words: `pub build -Denv=DEV`, or `pub build -Denv=QA`, etc.? Or do I have to add arguments for non-production environments (`-Denv=QA`) and omit all the arguments when doing my production build (`pub build`)?

Comment: Yes this was added just before 1.0. Here's the stable docs: https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/String.html#fromEnvironment and at the moment it doesn't appear pub build supports them. I filed a bug for it here: http://dartbug.com/15806

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again @Matt B (+1) - unfortunately that leaves me in sort of a stale mate. I need to use String.fromEnvironment, but I'm currently building all of my web files via `pub build`. If `pub build` doesn't support the -D args, then I'll need to use dart2js directly. **But**, if I need to use dart2js directly, I'm wondering what I'll be missing out on that `pub build` does for me automagically. Do you know offhand what extra steps I'll need to take in order to run dart2j but still accomplish all the same things that `pub build` does? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

To keep the same *build* you can read a variable from html which could be generated on server side.

For instance the server could generate (or replace with templating) the html file with :

```html
<script>
  // var serviceUrl = "@VALUE_OF_VAR@";
  var serviceUrl = "dev.myapp.com/someService";
</script>
```

and in dart client file :

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
main() {
  var serviceUrl = js.context['serviceUrl'];
}
```