# How to set java environment variable on mac

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables

How do I set a java environment variable that can be read with `System.getenv()` on Mac OS X Lion? I developing in Eclipse.

I used this command in the terminal `export VAR_NAME=Value` but `System.getEnv(VAR_NAME)` returns `null`.

I tried `java -DVAR_NAME=Value` but nothing is executed. I only get the java arguments help.

I created in my current project folder the file `.bash_profile` with the content: `export VAR_NAME=Value`. It's not working.

I also created the folder `.MacOSX` with a single file inside `environment.plist` and in this file I wrote the property and its value using XCode. Nothing is working.

How do I do it?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x?lq=1 this question was already asked (not related to Java).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It should very very rarely be necessary to mess with the global environment - provide a suitable launcher script instead. Using `java -D` won't affect the environment, you retrieve those values using `System.getProperty()`. (It's also probably more idiomatic to configure a Java program with those.)

Comment: You have to log in and log out for `environment.plist` changes to apply.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tips. I manage to fix it by adding the .MacOSX/environment.plist in my user folder. I din't know that '~' points to my user's folder... and of course logout/login.

I know this is a stupid thing to set, but I need to use some java apis that read some variables using System.getenv, so ...

Answer (score 9):

It is not clear what you are actually doing here.  If you are trying to set an environment variable for a Java command you are launching *from Eclipse*, then the simple solution is to set it via the Eclipse command launcher configuration.  Another alternative is to:

1. exit Eclipse,
2. run `export VAR_NAME=Value` in a command shell instance, and
3. launch Eclipse *from that same shell instance*.

---

Re the things you tried.

> I used this command in the terminal `export VAR_NAME=Value` but `System.getEnv(VAR_NAME)` returns `null`.

If you run the `export` command from a command prompt, and then immediately launch the command from the same command prompt, that *should* work.  The export command is telling the shell instance used by the command prompt to add `VAR_NAME` to this list of environment variables it exports *to child processes that started after running the `export`* command.  Child processes that have all ready been started *won't see the changes*.

I strongly suspect that you ran the `export` *after* you launched Eclipse ... or that you didn't start Eclipse from that shell instance.  If either of those two is true, the `export` command wouldn't affect Eclipse's environment variables which it (by default) passes on to any Java program you launch from Eclipse.

> I tried `java -DVAR_NAME=Value` but nothing is executed. I only get the java arguments help.

That fails for a couple of reasons:

- the `-DVAR_NAME=...` is setting a system property not an environment variable, and
- you haven't told `java` the name of the class that you want to start!

> I created in my current project folder the file `.bash_profile` with the content: `export VAR_NAME=Value`

That only affects new shell instances that are launched *after* you created the file.  It doesn't affect the existing one.

> I also created the folder .MacOSX with a single file inside environment.plist and in this file I wrote the property and its value using XCode.

I've no idea what that would do.  Where did you create that folder?

Comment: [The docs for `environment.plist`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html) state it's applied by the OS X login process.

Comment: It worked only creating .MacOSX/environment.plist in my user's folder and logout/login (or restart). Nothing else worked ... strange.

Answer (score 0):

1.open the Terminal

2.export VAR_NAME=Value

3.open /Applications/Eclipse.app