# System.getenv() returns null when the environment variable exists

Tags: java, bash, environment-variables

I am trying to `System.getenv()` to get the value of an environment variable that I have set through my terminal (Mac), I also set the variable in my .bash_profile file and reloaded. After doing so, I echo'd the value and the correct value was printed to the terminal. When trying to retrieve the value of the variable (I made sure I was using the correct name in both my .bash_profile file and when using `System.getenv()`.

In the below code, I have replaced the name of the variable with **VAR_NAME**:

```
String varValue = System.getenv("VAR_NAME");
System.out.println("Value: " + varValue);
```

In my .bash_profile:

```
export VAR_NAME="foo"
```

"null" is printed when I print out the value of `varValue`.

What could be the cause of this?

**Edit:** I followed the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x?lq=1%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B), restarted Eclipse and it worked!

Comment: How are you running the application? Does `printenv | grep VAR_NAME` in your shell show the value?

Comment: It does, and I'm running it through Eclipse @EtanReisner

Comment: You are running your shell command in Eclipse?

Comment: Can you check if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562156/how-to-set-java-environment-variable-on-mac or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x?lq=1
answer your question ?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Nope, I'm running the application via Eclipse

Comment: So the answers recommended by JFPicard should help you. The issue is to understand that an environment variable only affects what's in the same process where it was set or its child processes. And .profile only affects terminal sessions.

Comment: @JFPicard Thanks! I followed the second link you gave me and it worked. If you post it as an answer here, I'll mark it as correct so others know I have an accepted answer.

Comment: The answer to this should be more general in my opinion - one should know that environment variables go only down the process tree and only when a process is launched. Eclipse is a child process of your shell - hence, it inherited all the environment variables that were defined on your shell **when you launched it**.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The answer to this question is more general than just `System.getenv()` in Java.

Every process has its own independent copy of environment variables, while the environment variables only go down the process tree and are copied from parent to child only when the child process is created. In your case, your shell, which itself is a process, started/created the Eclipse process. Therefore, Eclipse is a **child process** of your shell and therefore, the environment variables defined on your Eclipse instance are a copy of those that had been defined on your shell **when you launched Eclipse**.

You probably defined the environment variable on your shell **after** you had launched Eclipse. Hence, Eclipse and the child Java processes it created, would never "know" about your new environment variable.

Due to this behavior, actually the solution here is to exit Eclipse and launch it again from your shell, in which the environment variable **is already defined**. Another option is to go to the run configuration of the project and define there the environment variable.

P.S.

1. Obviously, if you restart your computer, the environment variables you have defined on your shell will not be saved, simply since the shell process you defined the variables on will be gone.
2. If you use **bash**, then by adding the environment variable setting command to the file `~/.bashrc`, which is executed each time a bash process is started, you can simulate the behavior of permanent environment variables.
3. There are additional ways to define permanent environment variables. You can take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile) for more information.

Comment: The environment variable was in fact defined before launching Eclipse, I even restarted my computer after defining the variable back when it wasn't working as intended. The answer given in the link I gave in my OP fixed the issue.

Comment: It of course didn't work after you restarted the computer, as these variables are defined per process. They don't stay defined forever...

Comment: You can imagine the environment variables mechanism as a hash-table that exists along a process. You can always update it by adding/removing/changing variables. When you close the process (e.g. by exiting the shell or by restarting your computer), this hash table dies with the process. Another important thing I've already written in the answer is that every process inherits (actually copies) this hash table from the process which created it, at the creation time. After the creation, they have different hash tables, none of them knows about the other

Comment: If you understand this theory, you will understand why the solution in your link worked for you

Comment: It worked when I compiled file from console. Means it was not available in eclipse. Thanks for help you saved my time.

Comment: I don't run Eclipse from the shell and the environment variable is still null. Why do I have to run Eclipse for this to work ? Shouldn't this environment variable be accessible anywhere like `PATH` ?

Comment: Just an observation: if you're Windows user, restarting Eclipse won't work for this approach, you need to explicitly **Close** and **Open** the IDE again to get the variables applied.

Comment: In Windows, in addition to "local" environment variables, which are described in the answer, there are global "permanent" environment variables. If you define a "local" variable on the shell and then open Eclipse not from that specific shell, this variable will of course not be passed to Eclipse. Only in Windows, using permanent environment  variables, one can open Eclipse by clicking on its Icon and have it with the environment variables set (not only for Eclipse, but for any launched application)

Comment: How can I made a new variable and using it forever and from any where (not in the same shell) ?

Comment: @NguyễnThắng If you work in linux, you may need to edit `~/.bashrc` (given that you're using `bash` as a shell, else, you'll need to edit a file with similar name that is related to your shell). All the commands in `~/.bashrc` are executed every time `bash` shell is starting. So adding the `export` command in this file should do the work. In windows, take a look at this: http://www.forbeslindesay.co.uk/post/42833119552/permanently-set-environment-variables-on-windows

Comment: I added to /etc/environment. It's work :D

Comment: Once i define the variable within my `.bash_profile`,  now System.getEnv works.  Thanks.    I think using System.getProperty is better because it gives more flexibility.