# System getenv() is giving null in ubuntu, same code working in mac

Tags: java, linux, apache-spark

I am new to Java. I am using `System.getenv("SPARK_HOME")` to get the spark home path in given machine. When the Java application runs on ubuntu machine it gives `null`. The above property is set in bashrc (did `source .bashrc`). Tested through `echo $SPARK_HOME` which prints the value and also with `printenv |grep SPARK_HOME`.

I referred this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782467/system-getenv-returns-null-when-the-environment-variable-exists), but it dint help to solve my problem.

Comment: How are you invoking Java? If it's not from an interactive, non-login shell, bashrc wouldn't have been run.

Comment: Invoking java using `java -jar application.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the jar run the following command:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc

$ java -jar myJar.java
```

Comment: This worked, java application now able to get the system environment properties