# How to use environment variables with application.properties in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jwt, environment-variables

I am trying to configure my application.properties to take the value from the system variables I've set. The problem is that it won't work no matter what I do. I've tried using a custom class configuration with DataSource from [this example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/) still no success. All I was able to find on stackoverflow are links pointing to the [official docs.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.maps) Unfortunately that's a dead end since it doesn't say anything and there are no examples for what I'm trying to achieve. I also found examples like `spring.datasource.url = ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}` and everyone is saying that spring will know how to automatically take the environment variables. Well surprise, it doesn't.

I also found examples like `spring.datasource.password = ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:the_actual_password)` or `spring.datasource.url = #{SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:#{'the_actual_url'}}` which is totally not what I need and it's pretty useless if you ask me. I mean I could achieve the same thing writing `spring.datasource.password = the_actual_password`. The whole point is to hide the sensitive data..

Now, this being said I'll leave 2 screenshots with what I have. The reason why I am trying to achieve this is because when I'll push to GitHub I won't have to worry that my credentials or anything will be out in the open for everyone to see.

Here is how my environment variables look like:
[image]

Here is how application.properties look like:
[image]

Thank you in advance! And in case you have an answer to my question could you also let me know how can I achieve the same thing with environment variable but for the application.jwt properties?

Comment: You're looking for _relaxed property binding_. You don't _have_ to map `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` to `spring.datasource.url`; Boot does that for you automatically. It also handles overrides/priority automatically. (In general, environment beats properties file because environment is set at each launch.)

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look into that. I'll come back if I managed to make it work. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the solution was pretty... stupid, I suppose, but here it is. The reason why it didn't worked is because the environment variables were defined after IntelliJ first opened as described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782467/system-getenv-returns-null-when-the-environment-variable-exists). It seems like everything is working fine now.

I managed to achieve the functionality that I wanted.

In other words this:

```
spring.datasource.url = ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username = ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password = ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVERCLASSNAME}
```

Is now working perfectly.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You don't need this, you can ditch this as that works automatically. You can remove those properties from the `application.properties`.

Comment: @M.Deinum What do you mean by "ditch this", can you please describe it?

Comment: When you have an environment variable named `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` it will automatically map to `spring.datasource.url` so you don't need all of this.

Answer (score -1):

Have you used the correct annotations?

Given Properties as such:

```
root.test = ${TEST.VAR:-Test}
```

Environment variable like:

```
TEST.VAR = Something
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "root")
public class Test {
  private String test;

  public String getTest() {
    return test;
  }

  public void setTest(String test) {
    this.test = test;
  }

}
```

---

You can use `Records` by setting `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` on your Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class DemoApplication{...}
```

Defining Record like so:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "root")
public record Test (String test) {
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand what are you referring to :(. Are you talking about the DataSource custom class? If so please note that it's now what I'm trying to achieve. Basically what I need is whenever I put spring.datasource.username = ${SPRING_DATASROUCE_USERNAME} to take that value from the environment variable. "SPRING_DATASROUCE_USERNAME" being the environment variable that has the value 'user' or something. Thanks for such a quick response!

Comment: Are the environment variables available to the application? 

What do you get if you get and print the env var?```String envVar = System.getenv().get("SPRING_DATASROUCE_USERNAME")```

Comment: Oops you might be onto something. It prints null. What does it mean? Is the environment variable not set correctly?

Comment: Where/How have you try to set it?