# Adding /usr/local/bin (homebrew) to QtCreator search path for pkg-config on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, qt, homebrew, pkg-config

### Setup

- Using Qt Creator on Mac OSX mountain lion.
- Installed packages in /usr/local using homebrew.
- /usr/local/bin/pkg-config exists.
- Want to use pkgconfig through the project file

-

```
QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += protobuf #Or whatever package you want to try.
```

- /usr/local/bin being in the path, when I run `/Applications/Other/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/clang_64/bin/qmake myproject.pro` It runs fine.
- When I try to build the project through Qt Creator I see the error `sh: pkg-config: command not found` and the build fails.
- I already tried `launchctl setenv PATH $PATH` as suggested in [Environment variables in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x)

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I have done it so far is, in the qmake project file I hardcoded the pkgconfig path

```
mac {
  PKG_CONFIG = /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
}
```

I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution that someone can provide.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me as well. Looks quite neat to me.

Comment: For me nothing changed (