# install new version of python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have mac os x, recently I have install python version 3.2 before I had version 2.6.1. but when I type "python" in terminal it prints Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49). what does it mean? how can I use python 3.2 that have install this week?

Comment: I did and the result is: Tinas-MacBook-Pro:~ tina$ python3.
-bash: python3.: command not found

Comment: @sandra Which version of Mac OS X are you sporting?

Comment: rename the python3 executable to `python3`

Comment: then make sure that it is in your path and you can just do `python3 *args...`

Comment: How did you install python? (and I would use the current version python 3.3)

Comment: @jwarner112 version 10.6.8

Comment: just delete the python 2.6 version and then install python 3.2

Comment: oh I made a mistake and put dot after python3 and type python3.! now i worked ;)

Comment: @ Saad Abdullah I tried to delete 2.6 but I was not successful I use "sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6.1
" and also "sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.6"" but after this when I type python it print python 2.6.1. what should I do?

Comment: @sandra If you got your solution yourself, please make sure to answer your own question at the bottom and mark it as best answer. Also mark this as a community post. It may come in handy for future coders!

Comment: @jwarner112 tnx for advise, I did it

Comment: @sandra Also mark it as best answer and mark the entire question as a community question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on windows, but I'm hoping the solution will work cross-platform.

Your computer has something called `environment variables`. Basically, a list of locations with names on them like `python installation path`. Windows computers, and probably Mac ones too, use these to intercept commands in the terminal.

Likely, `python` is an environment variable in your machine but it points to your `python-2.6.1` installation.

From what I'm reading, you can edit your environment variables at `/etc/launchd.conf`, re-assigning your environment variable `python` to point at Python 3.2 instead of Python 2.6.1.

I hope this works for you; I don't have Mac OS X, so I can't easily help you navigate or know what you're looking at! But, good luck!

And Happy Coding!

EDIT: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x) some more information about environment variables in OS X!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using python I typed python3 in terminal and it was the solution