# Cannot set $GOPATH on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, go, environment-variables

I'm trying to set my `$GOPATH` variable to run some example code on my machine:

```
$ smitego-example go run main.go 
main.go:5:2: cannot find package "github.com/#GITHUB_USERNAME#/smitego" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/#GITHUB_USERNAME#/smitego (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)

$ smitego-example export $GOPATH=$HOME
-bash: export: `=/Users/#OSX_USERNAME#': not a valid identifier
```

[image]

Contents of `github.com/#GITHUB_USERNAME#/smitego/smitego.go`:

```
package smitego
```

How can I set my `GOPATH` so it works always and forever?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

**Update, as of Go 1.8**: If you're installing Go 1.8 (released: Feb 2017) or later, GOPATH is [automatically determined](https://rakyll.org/default-gopath/) by the Go toolchain for you.

It defaults to `$HOME/go` on macOS (nee OS X) - e.g. `/Users/matt/go/`. This makes getting started with Go even easier, and you can `go get <package>` right after installing Go.

---

**For the shell:** (the manual method)

~/.bash_profile should contain `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` and also `export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH`. The use of the `$` is important: make sure to note where I've used it (and where I have not).

**For Sublime Text:**

Sublime Text menu > Preferences > Package Settings > GoSublime > Settings: User

```
{
        "shell": ["/bin/bash"],
        "env": {"GOPATH": "/Users/#USERNAME#/go/"},
}
```

Make sure your `GOPATH` is not set to the full path of the package; just the root of your `go` folder where `src, pkg, and bin` reside. If you're not using [GoSublime](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime), I'd suggest installing that first.

Comment: `/usr/bin/bash` is usually `/bin/bash` on Mac or Linux.

Comment: in case this helps anyone if you install go via homebrew then the path will be like this:
`export PATH=/usr/local/opt/go@1.12/bin:$PATH`
(obviously update the version based on whatever you install)

Answer (score 60):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I investigated and found the cause: I am using zsh, not bash.

I need to add the following two lines to `~/.zshrc`:

```
export GOPATH=/Users/username/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: I also used this approach, and found there is a more generic way to define GOPATH.

`export GOPATH=$HOME/go`

Answer (score 18):

You don't put the `$` prefix on a variable when you're assigning it, only when you're reading it.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME
```

To make this permanent, put the command in your `.bash_profile`.

That will work for Terminal shells. If you need to set environment variables that will affect GUI applications, see [Environment variables in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x/4567308#4567308)

Comment: On OS X and using Sublime might the user have to use launchctl? I'm not sure .bash_profile would matter for GUI apps. So might need to do: launchctl setenv GOPATH=/path/to/home, and to make it last between boots add that to /etc/launchd.conf

Comment: Thanks! I learned something new today. However, now I'm getting: `cannot find package "github.com/sergiotapia/smitego" in any of: / /usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/sergiotapia/smitego /Users/sergiotapia/src/github.com/sergiotapia/smitego`. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know anything about `go`, so I can't help you with that part of it. My answer just shows the proper way to set environment variables; figuring out what you're supposed to set it to is a separate problem.

Comment: @Serg does 'go build' work from the command line after modifying your .bash_profile and sourcing it/reloading the shell?

Comment: what is the output of 'echo $GOPATH' ?

Comment: can you take this discussion out of the comments on my answer? I don't wish to be notified of all these questions.

Comment: @powerj1984: Output is: /Users/sergiotapia

Comment: Ha ha :) this should have been the correct answer though.

Answer (score 18):

1. Download and install Go tools
   https://golang.org/doc/install
2. Setup Go workspace

   `mkdir $HOME/go && cd $HOME/go`
   `mkdir bin pkg src`
3. Setup Go environment

   `sudo vi ~/.bash_profile`
   `export GOPATH=$HOME/go`
   `PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`

Test by creating, building and running a Go project

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/todsul/hello
touch $GOPATH/src/github.com/todsul/hello/hello.go
go install
hello
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO. I followed it verbatim and I was immediately writing go code.

Comment: Is "sudo vi ~/.bash_profile" creating a new .bash_profile file? If yes then where this file should be created exactly?

Comment: it will create it in the root directory. Note if you are using Oh My Zsh then you will have to add the go paths (step 3) to your `.zshrc` instead and then run `source .zshrc` if you want the changes to take effect without closing your terminal. Also you dont have to use vi ~/.bash_profile, you can open the file in atom or nano text editors as well

Comment: this answer got me going!  i'm getting back into mac development from doing windows 24/7 - so haven't used vim before - this helped, http://commandlinemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/vim.html

Answer (score 5):

The http://www.golang-book.com/guides/machine_setup#osx

only has instructions for setting the path on `~/.bashrc`, not `~/.bash_profile` which thanks to this thread was able to get my example file to build.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Other Mac users need to add the above to their `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: This guide now uses a program I wrote (github.com/badgerodon/penv) which saves environment variables for OSX using launchctl (https://github.com/badgerodon/penv/blob/master/darwin_dao.go). AFAIK this is the only way to set environment variables reliably in OSX.

Comment: Heavily advice against this, your `GOPATH` **IS** your home directory.  I (and many other comments) recommend setting `GOPATH` to `$HOME/go`

Answer (score 5):

After installing go with brew or with package this solved my problem:

```
export GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
export GOPATH="$HOME/Documents/goWorkSpace"
export PATH="$HOME/Documents/goWorkSpace/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Worked for me Big Sur M1, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

on macOS High Sierra Version 10.3.3, Go[go version go1.10.1 darwin/amd64] Installed here :

[image: Go Install Location]

Added following on :~/.bashrc

```
export GOPATH=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

and then Go Works

[image: Go Works]

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution

add:

```bash
export GOPATH=/Users/$USER/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

into your boot script (normally: `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`)

Answer (score -1):

People working with the latest macs and above Catalina version,
you guys need to update the .zshrc file instead of .bash.

**Add the following two lines to ~/.zshrc:**

export GOPATH=/Users/username/go

export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH

it should work.!!

This got change a while back, please refer to the link below to understand why .zshrc and not .bash_profile
https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/56921-moving-from-bash-to-zsh-terminal-changes-in-macos-catalina/