# $GOPATH value keeps reseting to empty during new sessions of the terminal

Tags: go

I have installed GO on my Mac Book using the 10.8+ installer from golang.org, and I have set up a workspace. After running both these commands: `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` and `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`, echoing the GOPATH does return a value of `/Users/dipen/go`; however, after restarting the terminal, the echoing the GOPATH returns nothing. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to put these commands into your `.bash_profile` on OSX .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot set $GOPATH on Mac OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499337/cannot-set-gopath-on-mac-osx)

Comment: @Intermernet Thanks it worked, I added those exact files and restarted the terminal.

Comment: @Dipen good to hear. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: Ok. I do same way oh my macbook. Also I have VPS running Ubuntu 14 which I access via SSH only for sure. Due to interactive non interactive shell distinction ~/.bashrc not always sourced.  Which profile or rc guaranteed to be sourced on Ubuntu in all case?

Comment: That's probably worthy of a separate question, and might already have an answer here.