# GOPATH variable not persisting

Tags: go

I'm setting the $GOPATH using `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` as per GoLang's instructions and everything works fine. When I `echo` out the path it shows what I set it to.

However, if I close my terminal and re-open it the $GOPATH is no longer what I set it to.

I guess my question is how can I make the new $GOPATH persist?

Comment: Where exactly do you set it? In ~/.bashrc?

Comment: No I'm not using a .bashrc - I'm not sure how to do this part. Could you show me?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: yes i am using Ubuntu

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I SET the GOPATH environment variable on Ubuntu? What file must I edit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001387/how-do-i-set-the-gopath-environment-variable-on-ubuntu-what-file-must-i-edit)

Comment: see the answer in the question I've linked above.

Comment: i've seen that - I can't see the answer - there is no accepted anwser

Comment: This is a Linux/bash question and it's because export only sets the env variable for the current session...

Comment: any chance you could show me how to write it to a file then?

Comment: @tommyd456 I've provided a step by step answer. Not sure what your skill level with Ubuntu is but these as I noted this is Linux/bash and nothing to do with Go so you don't want to look on SO for future reference. SuperUser or Ubuntu stackexchange for example are far more appropriate for the type of answer I've provided.

Comment: appreciate that - very low by the way (skill level) ha ha

Comment: related to [$GOPATH value keeps reseting to empty during new sessions of the terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006265/gopath-value-keeps-reseting-to-empty-during-new-sessions-of-the-terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you know this should be answered in general form on SuperUser or something other than here. Regardless here's the steps to make it so this is always set in your session;

```
cd ~
vi .bashrc
//page down, end whatever to get to bottom of file if it's not new
press i to insert, add export GOPATH=$HOME/go
press escape
:w
:q
```

Answer (score 0):

Open you terminal (you can use any text editor, like: gedit, vi or vim).

```
   gedit ~/.bashrc
```

go to the end of file and edit with the following lines:

```
   export GOPATH=$HOME/go
   export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Assuming that /usr/lib/go is your GOROOT

to know your GOROOT you can do:

```
   go env
```

or

```
   which go
```

Comment: setting GOROOT allows you to put $GOROOT/bin in your path. There's no problem in set GOROOT

Comment: From many posts on the mailing list: "In general, never set GOROOT." Also see: [You don’t need to set GOROOT, really](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really). Only set it if you absolutely need to, otherwise it will eventually cause problems.

Comment: Ok, fixed. I can't really see BIG problems, but ok.

Comment: Maybe it's only a big problem for those of us who regularly answer questions on the ML caused by setting GOROOT (and those affected of course) ;)

Answer (score 0):

To make Felix's answer more simpler you could run the below commands while not breaking your head with `vim`

```
echo "export GOPATH=$HOME/go" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```