# GOPATH not being automatically set?

Tags: macos, go, installation, gopath

I'm installing Golang on my MacBook.

According to multiple sources ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21506074/8516041)), Golang 1.8 and onwards automatically sets GOPATH.

If I run the command `go env gopath` in Terminal, nothing is returned. Does this mean the GOPATH variable is not set?

I have attempted to set it manually with `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` (as per this [example](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH)).

Yet this still returns nothing.

I have tried reinstalling Golang. This works on my Windows machine, just not MacOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go will use a default for GOPATH. Run the `go env` command to see the value.

Run the `go env GOPATH` command for just the GOPATH value.

Comment: Ah, I see it in this list. Do you know why this wasn't being returned when I entered go env gopath? Thanks!

Comment: Run `go env GOPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to run `go env GOPATH` instead of `go env gopath`. Notice the difference in capitalization. Just running `go env` would list all `go` variables.