# Why is an environmental variable not expanded in one of my machine but work on the other in Vim?

Tags: vim, environment-variables

I use two Macs and use the same `~/.vimrc` file, which is stored at Dropbox, and add a symbolic link to it from within both computers at the same location, `~/.vimrc`. So I don't think there is any difference whatsoever between the two computer's `~/.vimrc` file.

However, when I try to call `:tabnew $R` from within one computer's MacVim application, the environmental variable is not expanded correctly. The command works on my other computer, and I set `$R` to `~/r` in both of my Macs.

So what does prevent one from being expanded but nonetheless it works on the other? Even `echo $R` not working on the computer...

[The official doc](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Environment_variables) implies that I don't need to set any configuration to properly expand the environmental variable. Also, the environmental variable correctly is expanded in my Terminal.

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: how ecological is an environmental variable? :)

Comment: The question is how environment variables are defined in a GUI application on a Mac.  That is explained here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x .  I think this counts as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the reason it prevented environment variables from being expanded is that I switched to zsh shell, and it doesn't load those environment variables defined in `~/.zshrc` when MacVim is launched. When I used bash shell, I defined all of those variables in `~/.bash_profile`.

The solution is to define those variables in `~/.zshenv`, not `~/.zshrc.` I suspect that the MacVim is assumed to be launched as a shell script, and when a command is executed as a shell script in zsh, only `~/.zshenv` is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If even `echo $R` is not working, it means the environment variable `R` simply is not defined on that machine, so there's also nothing to expand in your `.vimrc`.