# Maven not finding Java even though it is set

Tags: java, maven

Beating my head on the wall with this. Using Mac 10.10 and my java -version works but mvn -version gives me

`error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

and that's not even my correct jdk. Here is what my bash_profile looks like:export

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home

export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.3
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m-Xmx512m
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

Comment: Try changing PATH entries order

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Found the solution to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661734/maven-not-recognizing-java-home-being-set-in-bash-profile?noredirect=1#comment42086840_26661734

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this. I needed to restart the Terminal app. For it to pick up the new bash_profile changes.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that several times with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

That is (maybe) because iOS has a default Java installed and you have another Java VM that you downloaded yourself.

Try this, instead of defining the java home, let the OS use the one installed. In your profile, or on a shell script do this

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

Or whatever version of java you are using. For example, if you have java 6 and 7 installed, then running

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

will select java 7, whereas

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
```

will let you use Java 6.

*NOTE the back ticks.*

Comment: Thank you. That didn't work. Definitely seems like an OS conflict but I cannot track it down. A lot of posts also say to try `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Execute one of the commands above in Terminal.app on a command line and then execute `mvn` immediately after. If this does not work then your java installation or something else in your environment is hosed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the mvn.sh script, make sure you have not set the JAVA_HOME in it. Or redownload a maven package and unpack.
And check /etc/launchd.conf, have you set a JAVA_HOME in it?

Comment: thanks. Did not hard code anything in mvn.sh and do not have launchd.conf file.

Comment: Can you restart terminal and echo $JAVA_HOME to check it?

Answer (score 0):

install maven in **mac**/linux (mac in your case), should following this http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi  section:**Unix-based Operating Systems (Linux, Solaris and Mac OS X)**

if your default terminal is bash (`echo $SHELL` will output something like: /bin/**bash**)
run `echo $JAVA_HOME` first before run mvn.

```
isaacdong-imac:~ isaac$ echo $SHELL /bin/bash 
isaacdong-imac:~ isaac$
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
isaacdong-imac:~ isaac$
```

if your JAVA_HOME is empty, please note this:
export command ONLY current env of shell process. when you open a new shell or restart mac. export effect is gone.

see this: [Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: Please don't guess. There is no such file as mvn.sh

Comment: Thank you. I do have bash and $JAVA_HOME shows my correct jdk path. But mvn -version still shows `We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` which is not even my incorrect jdk.

Comment: *export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m-Xmx512m* have to be changed to *export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"*

Comment: *export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m-Xmx512m* have to be changed to *export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"*. please show me your original .bash_profile(there is a dot before bash) content, and original shell log:commands and outputs.