# Maven not recognizing JAVA_HOME being set in bash_profile

Tags: java, maven

Going on nearly 2 days wasted trying to get maven properly installed. These are my outputs. Why in the world is maven defaulting to some jdk I don't even have??? I have tried a million different solutios proposed from goole searches and nothing!!! Help. I have not made any changes to any config files such as `mvn.sh`.

```
System: Mac
OS=Yosemite 10.10
Java=Oracle 1.8 JDK
```

contents of .bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

terminal commands:

```
java -version -> 
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

mvn -version -> 
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
    We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Comment: Have you checked whether your installed maven works with java 8 or not!

Comment: please close this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642617/maven-not-finding-java-even-though-it-is-set/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else happens to run into this the crazy stupid solution was that I had an old .mavenrc file in home directory that was causing the conflict.