# Xcode snapshot fails when using git lfs

Tags: xcode, git

I have git set up with the [git-lfs extension](https://git-lfs.github.com). When using Xcode 6 to do a search and replace then it uses git internally to take a snapshot of the project before doing the replace. Now that I am using lfs the snapshot fails with the message:

```
error: copy-fd: write returned Broken pipe
error: cannot feed the input to external filter git lfs clean %f
error: external filter git lfs clean %f failed 1
error: external filter git lfs clean %f failed
fatal: xxxx: clean filter 'lfs' failed
```

Is it possible to configure Xcode to use the version of git with the lfs extension installed? Or update the version of git used by Xcode to add the lfs extension?

I tried installing git-lfs in the same directory as git used by Xcode but that does not help.

```
cp git-lfs /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've installed git-lfs via homebrew, so that it's in `/usr/local/bin`, and updated your `PATH` to match. The problem is that GUI apps don't inherit your updated `PATH` from the shell, because their parent process is `launchd`. So when Xcode tries to run `git`, Git fails because it can't locate `git-lfs`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567308/16935) talks about the various ways that OS X apps pick up their environment, and how you can modify the defaults in OS X 10.9 and earlier.

For Yosemite, it seems that `/etc/launchd.conf` is no longer supported, and so the fix is slightly different: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this is the cause. I have installed git-lfs for both /user/bin , /user/local/bin and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin

Comment: @combinatorial did you find a solution?

Comment: @LarsSchneider no I did not