# C# Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(...) Not Working on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono

I am running a console application on OSX that has the following...

```cs
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    string mongoEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONGO_ENDPOINT");

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(mongoEndpoint))
    {
        _log.Fatal("Invalid Mongo Endpoint");
        throw new Exception("Invalid Mongo Endpoint");
    }
}
```

I have added a `MONGO_ENDPOINT` environment variable to my `~/.bash_profile` and when I run `echo $MONGO_ENDPOINT` it outputs the correct value.

However, when I run my console application from Xamarin Studio in OSX, it returns null.

I tried running the following to see if it was all environment variables, and it returned the correct value.

```
Console.Out.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME"));
```

and it outputted `/usr/myname` perfectly fine.

Any reason why it would not be able to find this environment variable?

Comment: I had this problem, found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3756674/3708323

Answer (score 6):

OS-X GUI apps will not inherit your private/custom env vars that are defined via a shell (bash, zsh, etc...) if they are launched from Finder/Spotlight. You have two choices:

1) Start Xamarin Studio from the cmd line so your current users' environment will be used:

```
/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/XamarinStudio &
```

2) If you want user environment vars available to GUI apps launched from Finder/Spotlight you need to modify your `/etc/launchd.conf`, see this SO answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3756686/4984832

[Runtime Configuration Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/000-Introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000170-SW1)