# Exporting a variable set in terminal to R

Tags: r, terminal, echo

I am running Mac OS High Sierra with RStudio.

I want to export a terminal set variable to RStudio, but echo and getenv currently show no output:

**In terminal:**

```
export testexpvar="testworks"

###I can echo in the terminal
echo $testexpvar
testworks
```

**In RStudio console:**

```
###I can't echo in R:
system("echo $testexpvar") ### no output at all

Sys.getenv("testexpvar")
[1] ""
```

Comment: Unless you are starting R or RStudio from the terminal *where you set the variable*, the variable is visible only to that process and children processes. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/603785/3358272