# Error running a simple hello_world program

Tags: fortran

I need to download Fortran to complete my project. I have tried following the video on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HakTEhU3Q9U) but I get an error right at the end. I can't compile a simple 'hello_world' program.

I am new to programming so I am not familiar with computing terminology.  I have downloaded java, Eclipse, and Fortran. When I open Eclipse and I try to compile a simple program I get an error.

```
make all 
Building file: ../helloFortran.f95
/bin/sh: gfortran: command not found
Invoking: GNU Fortran Compiler
gfortran -funderscoring -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "helloFortran.o" "../helloFortran.f95"
make: *** [helloFortran.o] Error 127
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

17:00:47 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 94ms)
```

The program I am trying to run is simply this.

```
    program helloFortran
    implicit none
    print*, "Fortran is great"
end program helloFortran
```

I also have a text file which I do not know what it is for.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gfortran/bin
$HOME/eclipse/parallel-2018-12/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/
eclipse -data $HOME/documents/workspace
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Your question is not Fortran 95 specific anyway.

Comment: Notice the `/bin/sh: gfortran: command not found`, that will be the key. What happens when you try to execute `gfortran` on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the file `EclipseFortran.sh` containing

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gfortran/bin $HOME/eclipse/parallel-2018-12/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -data $HOME/documents/workspace
```

The PATH line is a *single* line, up to `workspace`. Then, type

```
bash EclipseFortran.sh
```

and this should launch eclipse with knowledge of gfortran's location.

This is a bit unusual to setup the environment in this way. You can define environment variables on Mac OS for GUI applications. I am not using Mac OS so I can suggest to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3756674/3327666

```
launchctl setenv PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gfortran/bin
```

Comment: Im not sure when this changed but launchctl path was different for me. It is now: launchctl setenv PATH $PATH:/usr/local/bin/gfortran

Comment: It should be `launchctl setenv PATH $PATH:/usr/local/bin/` then. The PATH variable goes to the directory containing the executable programs, not to the executable file.