# How to source a file from launchctl

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables, launchctl

I'm trying to `source` a file from a `launch agent`, but it's unclear how to accomplish that (or if it's even possible). I know it's easy to `setenv` for single variables, but I need to bring in a bunch of them, so `source` is what I need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>my.sourcerer</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>source</string>
        <string>my_file.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/path/to/source</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This loads and starts without any issue it seems:

```
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.sourcerer.plist
$ launchctl start ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.sourcerer.plist
```

But when I `printenv` none of my sourced environment variables show up. If manually I do:

```
$ source /path/to/source/my_file.sh
$ printenv
```

Then all of the variables show up. Why doesn't the `launchctl` agent seem to load the variables into my environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment variables in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: What `source` does is run commands from a file *in the current shell*, and that doesn't make sense except in a shell; launchd isn't a shell, so it doesn't make sense there. But even if you could, I don't think it would do what you want. Each process has its own environment variables (though child processes start with a copy of their parent's environment), so if you could use `source` there it would set the variables *for the launchd process*, not for your shell processes.

Comment: Launchd runs programs. The `source` command is a shell builtin. It is not a program. If you look at */var/log/system.log* you should see error messages related to launching your `my.sourcerer.plist` config. Furthermore, you can't modify the environment of your current shell (or any other already running process) setting an env var in a process created by launchd. What is it you're really trying to do?

Comment: @GordonDavisson: That makes sense, but then why then would I have some apps that `setenv` from a launch agent? Or rather, why would it be useful rather than setting it in `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: @KurtisRader: I have an app (not one I created) that requires it to use `source initialize` to setup environment variables before it runs. I was hoping that I could streamline the process by having the environment variables automatically set at boot so that process was not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments to the question I'm going to go out on a limb and try to answer the question.

It seems you want to launch a program when you login rather than manually after you open your first terminal session. The solution is to create a script that includes the necessary `source` command to initialize the environment. Then make that script  pathname the first arg of your *~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.sourcerer.plist* config.

You could also statically set those vars via `launchctl setenv`. But I would not recommend that approach because it obviously isn't dynamic. That is, if the output of the `source`d script ever changes the statically set env vars inherited by every process would not change.jj

Comment: How would I be able to confirm that the environment variables that I source in the script are set when I login?

Comment: When I wrote "login" above I meant logging in to the desktop environment after booting the computer. And I assumed you would launch the program that needs the env vars from the same script you had launchd run. If you want to be able to run that program from an interactive shell you'll need to put the `source` command in the appropriate shell config file; e.g., *~/.bashrc*. I get the distinct sense you're trying to make a simple problem more complicated than it needs to be.