# Will I lose my environment variables if I upgrade to macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos

I've heard that it's best to wait after a new OS comes out until a few updates come in so that the build is a bit more stable. However, I'm also wondering if I will have to set up my environment, PATH, etc again after upgrading. Will updating change anything or will everything be the same as before?

(I'm currently on macOS Mojave 10.14.6)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour] and [ask] .  OS questions belong at sister site SuperUser.com

Comment: Don't update your Mac. The current version of 10.15 is soo unstable. I hope they [Apple] will publish some updates soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that environment variables can live in [different places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567308/4321), so it may depend on which ones you're referring to.

Usually if Mac OS upgrades need to change a file that you're likely to customize, like the httpd.conf file, they'll make a backup first. But there's no guarantee; it's good to keep a Time Machine backup handy from before you upgrade. With that you can copy in anything that got lost.

Also note that Catalina is switching the default shell from bash to zsh, so if you have environment variables in .bash_profile or .bashrc, those will be ignored. You can switch back to bash if you want, or [configure zsh with similar settings](https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh/).

Answer (score 0):

### Starting with macOS Catalina --  by default it takes zsh and hence you need to change in zprofile. Please follow below steps

1. touch ~/.zprofile;  (// This will create the profile)
2. open ~/.zprofile;   (Open this in an editor)

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home
export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/myuser/Documents/installs/gradle-6.8.3

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myuser/Documents/installs/gradle-6.8.3/bin

3. source ~/.zprofile (Execute the new .zprofile by either restarting the terminal window or using this)